# How to update user profile custom fields

Tags: custom-field, forms, user-meta

I have created custom fields on my registration form, such as 'telephone', using [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/). I have found a way to make them appear in the backend (on the User page) but I can't update those fields.

What do I need to do in order to be able to update them?

Register-form.php:

```
<label for="telephone<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Telephone', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="telephone"  id="pays<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'telephone' ); ?>"/>
```

Functions.php:

```
<?php
function custom_user_profile_fields($user) {
?>
<table class="form-table">
<tr>
    <th>
        <label for="telephone"><?php _e('Téléphone'); ?></label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'telephone', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />     
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields');
?>
```

Comment: Theme My Login has an option 'Enable Themed Profiles' if you check that box you should see any extra fields as part of the user profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [update_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) to update the fields. You can add this in functions.php of your child theme.

```
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
    return false; 
}

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'telephone', $_POST['telephone'] );   
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to update custom field value for user

```
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value );
```

For more information. Please [visit](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)